# FreeBSD 11.3 p5 AMD64 cant upgrade to RELEASE-12 config thinks its already 12

Tags: freebsd, upgrade

Can't upgrade to release 12 as freebsd-update thinks I'm updating **FROM** release 12 not **TO** release 12.

root@bsdxp:~ # uname -mrs
FreeBSD 11.3-RELEASE-p5 amd64

root@bsdxp:~ # freebsd-update -r 12-RELEASE upgrade
src component not installed, skipped
Looking up update.FreeBSD.org mirrors... 3 mirrors found.
Fetching metadata signature for 11.3-RELEASE from update4.freebsd.org... done.
Fetching metadata index... done.
Inspecting system... done.

The following components of FreeBSD seem to be installed:
kernel/generic world/base world/lib32

The following components of FreeBSD do not seem to be installed:
kernel/generic-dbg world/base-dbg world/doc world/lib32-dbg

Does this look reasonable (y/n)? y

Fetching metadata signature for 12-RELEASE from update4.freebsd.org... failed.
Fetching metadata signature for 12-RELEASE from update1.freebsd.org... failed.
Fetching metadata signature for 12-RELEASE from update2.freebsd.org... failed.
No mirrors remaining, giving up.

```
This may be because upgrading **from** this platform (amd64)
or release (12-RELEASE) is unsupported by freebsd-update.
```

Only platforms with Tier 1 support can be upgraded by freebsd-update.
See https://www.freebsd.org/platforms/index.html for more info.

If unsupported, FreeBSD must be upgraded by source.
root@bsdxp:~ # /usr/sbin/freebsd-update install
src component not installed, skipped
No updates are available to install.
Run '/usr/sbin/freebsd-update fetch' first.
root@bsdxp:~

I tried this on 2 instances - both gave the same result. They both say they are 11.3 p-5 abut when I attempt to upgrade to 12 the error message implies something thinks it's already at 12.

Thoughts?

Comment: It should be `-r 12.0-RELEASE`.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense because I got it to work using -r 12.0

Answer (score 2):

solved by using:

```
freebsd-update -r 12.0 upgrade
```

instead of:

```
freebsd-update -r 12-RELEASE upgrade
```